# Variável pom.xml que mostra a localização do arquivo

Tags: java, maven

Eu uso o Ubuntu 18.04.

Meu projeto está numa partição NTFS.

Eu preciso saber qual a variável que mostra o local que está o arquivo pom.xml

Estou usando a variável ${basic}, mas não está mostrando o local onde o arquivo pom.xml está.

Está mostrando o diretório: /home/gustavo/.m2/repository/

O estranho é que essa variável funciona no Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente usar o

```
${project.basedir}
```

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+Properties+Guide

Você pode tentar imprimir as variáveis para verificar.

Coloquei um exemplo no [Github](https://github.com/rafaelchagasb/answers-stackoverflow/blob/master/pt.stackoverflow.com/maven/453410/example/pom.xml). Basta executar o **mvn clean install** e verificar o arquivo properties.txt.

Fiz o teste no Ubuntu 20.04 e funcionou como esperado.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>ru.yaal.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>write-text-files-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <charset>UTF-8</charset>
                    <files>
                        <file>
                            <path>properties.txt</path>
                            <lines>
                                <line>=== JAVA PROPERTIES ===</line>
                                <line>Java vendor: ${java.vendor}</line>
                                <line>Java version: ${java.version}</line>
                                <line>Java home: ${java.home}</line>
                                <line>=== OS ENVIRONMENT ===</line>
                                <line>User dir: ${env.HOME}</line>
                                <line>=== MAVEN SETTINGS.XML ===</line>
                                <line>Offline: ${settings.offline}</line>
                                <line>=== Maven Properties Guide ===</line>
                                <line>Description:                          ${project.description}</line>
                                <line>project.basedir:                      ${project.basedir} </line>
                                <line>project.build.directory:              ${project.build.directory}</line>
                                <line>project.build.outputDirectory:        ${project.build.outputDirectory}</line>
                                <line>project.build.testOutputDirectory:    ${project.build.testOutputDirectory}</line>
                                <line>project.build.sourceDirectory:        ${project.build.sourceDirectory}</line>
                                <line>project.build.testSourceDirectory:    ${project.build.testSourceDirectory}</line>
                                <line>project.build.finalName:              ${project.build.finalName}</line>
                                <line>project.version:                      ${project.version}</line>
                                <line>settings.localRepository:             ${settings.localRepository}</line>
                                <line>basic:                                ${basic}</line>
                            </lines>
                        </file>
                    </files>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>write-text-files</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>write-text-files</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Oi Rafael, já fiz isso. O estranho é que essas variáveis funcionam no Windows 10. Meu ambiente é Linux 18.04 LTS, e o eclipse que uso tem a mesma versão (Oxygem March 2018)

Comment: Atualizei a resposta. Fiz o teste no Linux e funcionou corretamente. Talvez o seu pom.xml tenha alguma configuração que esteja mudando a raiz do projeto. Verifique o exemplo que coloquei na resposta e diga o que ele imprime no seu ambiente.

Comment: Segui suas instruções Rafael e as variáveis estão apontando para o lugar correto: (project.basedir: /media/gustavo/Novo volume/GIT/sistemas/Comuns/commons-ejb). Mas eu não consigo concatenar essa variável com uma outra URL na propriedade systemPath em dependencies no Ubuntu 18, só fuciona no Windows 10. Segue a linha do pom.xml: <systemPath>${project.basedir}../../commons/target/commons-0.0.1.jar</systemPath>

Comment: Qual a estrutura de pasta do seu projeto Gustavo?

Comment: eu tenho um projeto COMMONS-EJB que está no caminho: /media/gustavo/Novo volume/GIT/sistemas/Comuns/commons-ejb. Esse projeto tem uma dependência com outro projeto COMMONS que está no seguinte caminho: /media/gustavo/Novo volume/GIT/sistemas/Comuns/commons

Comment: No eclipse eu abri a aba "Effective pom" e ele está mostrando no systemPath o seguinte caminho: <systemPath>/media/gustavo/Novo volume/GIT/sistemas/Comuns/commons-ejb../../commons/target/commons-0.0.1.jar</systemPath>. Ele não está reconhecendo os caracteres "../../" para voltar 2 pastas. O estranho é que no Windows 10 funciona

Comment: @GustavoMenezes Pelo seu relato acho que o seu problema na verdade é de trabalhar com dependencias no maven. Eu atualizei o projeto do Github com um projeto com essa estrutura que você está querendo. Importe o projeto e olhei a estrutura de <modules> do pom e como eles se relacionam. O systempath só é indicado em casos onde uma dependencia não está disponível em algum repositório maven. Para utilizar dependencias dentro de uma mesma estrutura você pode utilizar a referencia diretamente no pom.xml.

Comment: Oi Rafael, realmente essas dependências não estão no repositório maven, pois são códigos da empresa onde trabalho e os donos não querem que esteja disponível lá.

Comment: o diretório "Comuns" é apenas uma pasta do sistema operacional, serve só para organização dos arquivos no computador. Pelo que vi no GitHub você utilizou esse "Comuns" como um projeto maven para agrupar o COMMONS e COMMONS-EJB, certo?

Comment: eu vi a propriedade do "systemPath" em "dependencies", no "Effective pom" quando o arquivo pom.xml está no windows. Tem o seguinte caminho: <systemPath>D:\GIT\sistemas\Comuns\commons-ejb../../commons/target/commons-0.0.1.jar</systemPath>. Acho que o problema é causado pela forma como o Windows e Ubuntu gerenciam suas pastas de arquivos, barras "/" no Linux e contrabarras no Windows "\"

Comment: Dê uma olhada no projeto do Github mais uma vez. Eu fiz aqui no meu Linux(ubuntu 20.04) e funcionou.

<groupId>br.com.rafaelchagasb</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache-commons</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/../commons/commons-lang3-3.10.jar</systemPath>
   </dependency>

Comment: Boa noite Rafael! Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda, funcionou!!!